# How to create multiple conditions in Case command?

Tags: delphi, switch-statement, delphi-10-seattle

Ex:

```
var
 Msg: Cardinal;
case Msg of
      WM_CHAR:
      WM_KEYDOWN:
      WM_KEYUP:
        begin
         // Do something
        end;

    end;
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What error / behavior does it exhibit?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mirtheil, the error was on **:** of `WM_KEYDOWN` that said: "Expected *END* but received **:**".

Comment: I just want to say, if you read the documentation, non of your previous question including this would have found a place here, just read the documentation and all will be answered mostly, And when you reach that level then come ask here.

Comment: For your convenience, here it is http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Case_Statements .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use commas to separate the labels:

```
var
  Msg: Cardinal;
... 
case Msg of
  WM_CHAR,
  WM_KEYDOWN,
  WM_KEYUP:
    begin
      // Do something
    end;
end;
```

As @SertacAkyuz mentioned, if the values are consecutive, you can do something like:

```
case Msg of
  WM_KEYDOWN .. WM_CHAR: // range 
    begin
      // Do something
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Sertac: yes, indeed, although I would probably not use it for such message constants. It can work if you know the exact order, but I don't (and don't want to memorize them either).

Comment: Yes, for this case it just makes the constants obscure. But good to know for when it makes sense, like: wm_keyfirst .. wm_keylast.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want "Do Something" to be executed in all three cases you have to separate the case labels with comma:

```
var
  Msg: Cardinal;

case Msg of
  WM_CHAR,
  WM_KEYDOWN,
  WM_KEYUP:
        begin
         // Do something
        end;
end;
```